# Remove staticwebassets in blazor webassembly not working

Tags: blazor-webassembly, nuget-package, .net-8.0, staticwebassets

I am trying to not include static web assets in a blazorwebassembly project since I don't need them. I use:

```
    <Target Name="ChooseEnabledStaticAssets" DependsOnTargets="ResolveStaticWebAssetsInputs" 
Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <StaticWebAsset Remove="**\*" />
      </ItemGroup>            
    </Target>
```

And when I build in release mode, static assets still generate. How to correct this or something else to disable project staticwebassets generation when built?

EDIT: I found something in the aspnet core source and twiked it:

```
<PropertyGroup>    
  <StaticWebAssetsEnabled1>false</StaticWebAssetsEnabled1>
  <StaticWebAsset></StaticWebAsset>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="ChooseEnabledStaticAssets" DependsOnTargets="ResolveStaticWebAssetsInputs"
        Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <StaticWebAsset Remove="**\*" />
    <Folder Remove="wwwroot" />     
  </ItemGroup>
  <DefineStaticWebAssets Condition="'$(StaticWebAssetsEnabled1)'=='false'">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assets" PropertyName="StaticWebAsset" />
  </DefineStaticWebAssets>
</Target>
```

Still this is not working.